# Persist members of an object that an entity "has" rather than the object itself

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, jpa-2.0

As a minimal example, if I have 2 classes like this:

```
    /* A is an entity while B is not. C is another class irrelevant 
for this problem. */
        class B{
             Integer bval1;
             Double bval2;
        }

        @Entity
        class A extends C {
             @Id
             @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
             Integer aid;
             @column
             Double aval1;
             @???
             B b;

        }
```

What do I fill at "???" (or somewhere else ) so that it gets persisted in a table with the structure as:

```
aid | aval1 | bval1 | bval2
```

Is this possible or should I restructure my classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make class B `@Embeddable`. That is what embeddable is for.

One JPA provider (`DataNucleus`) allows specification ofsomethig similar to a JPA `AttributeConverter` that converts the B to *multiple* columns (the standard `AttributeConverter` only converts to one column) so, if using that, you could avoid putting `@Embeddable` on your B class. That is clearly a vendor extension though, so non-portable if that is important to you.

Other than that, the answer is no you cannot do what you want.

Comment: Cool! @Embeddable seems like what I want.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To directly answer your question.
There is nothing you can fill in the ??? ONLY to achieve what you want.

If you can make Class B a @MappedSuperclass without making it a @Entity and make A extend B, you can achieve your goal. Note that you also need to make the attributes in Class B @Column.

This way B is not an @Entity and class A does not need to include the attributes in B, whew...

#### update:

Per comments with OP and updated question, I am afraid the answer would just be that it is impossible to do so.

Comment: Ah, I do not want to / cannot make it inherit B as in my actual problem A already inherits C.

Comment: @VivekVK well, I am afraid the answer would just be that it is impossible to do so.

Comment: Yeah, that was my feeling as well. Posted this to know if there is a way I do not know about. Let me wait for a while and if no others comes up with a solution, I will close this question. Would you mind adding your last comment as a part of your post?

Comment: Thanks for adding it!

Answer (score -1):

You can't replace **@???** with anything because your pojo has only one primary key.
And obviously there is no solution for your question.